# pre-commit AssertionError: black requires Python 3.6+

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Running pre-commit gives the error `AssertionError: black requires Python 3.6+`. But Python 3.8 is installed. The version of pre-commit is 1.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

Another installation of pre-commit (from Snap) was shadowing the correct one. Solved with these steps:

1. Remove the pre-commit installed with Snap: `snap remove pre-commit`.
2. Install it with Pip: `python -m pip install pre-commit`.